# How to archive files after snowpipe process

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

After loading files via `snowpipe` in `s3`, how can we send it to archive location. How to set dependency between `snowpipe` and file archival process. ?

Comment: What do you mean by archieving? Loading data to Snowflake using Snowpipe and then pushing some other data to an archive database in Snowflake?

Comment: Once files are loaded through Snowpipe , we need to move it to some other location as a backup.  How it can be automated.

Comment: Okay. Then the answer is below: There is no functionality from Snowflake. It's a functionality that you need within AWS.

Answer (score 2):

No tool that Snowflake makes available will allow you to do this automatically. You will need to use another method to check to see if the files have been loaded first, then move the files in S3 to another location. You could also set up a [lifecycle policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/create-lifecycle.html) in S3 to handle the archiving?

I don't really like the method of moving the files in S3 after they've been loaded, I think you should put them into their final location in S3 first and have Snowpipe load them from there. That way you don't have to move them again after they have been loaded.

Comment: thanks SimonD , what is another tool in this case.. ?

Comment: What Simon meant is that you will need to use a custom made tool/code to do this. In my case I used Python to load the files to stage(PUT) and I get the status as 'LOADED', I push the file to an archive location using the same python code

Comment: exactly what @RajibDeb said

Comment: thanks @Rajib Deb  , How did you set dependency between python script for archival process and snowpipe process.. Once snowpipe is completed then only python script should run.

Comment: @PIG - Rajib used a python script to do the loading and archiving of the file so the script would just wait until Snowpipe loaded it. Why exactly do you need to move the file after landing it into S3? Just land it in the final location and let Snowpipe load it from there?

Comment: SimonD , we have such requirement to have separate archival location for some processes. But i still didn't understand , how dependency set between python script and snowpipe.  Is snowpipe is being called within python script.? kindly answer.